# Combining multiple pretained models at the ouput stage in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have created four 3D-CNN models and each was trained on a different (but related) set of images, such that each set has images of a different perspective of the same objects. (i.e: n objects have images from 4 different perspectives, each model is associated to a single perspective).

```
def get_model(width=128, height=128, depth=4):


inputs = Input((width, height, depth, 3))

x = Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=8,padding='same', activation="relu")(inputs)
x = MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,data_format= "channels_first", padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)


x = Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=3,padding='same', activation="relu")(x)
x = MaxPool3D(pool_size=2,data_format= "channels_first", padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
x = Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

outputs = Dense(units=2, activation="sigmoid")(x)

# Define the model.
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
return model
```

I have now four pre-trained models, and I would like to combine them by removing the last dense layer (sigmoid) and instead, concatenating the dense layers of all the four models followed by an activation function (i.e: sigmoid). I would like to keep four input layers such that each will take an image of an object from one perspective. I have seen examples of concatenating an output layer of model_1 to the input layer of model_2, however, I am not sure how to deal with four separate input layers and concatenating towards the end of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have your pretrained model files named "A.h5" and "B.h5". You can simply load them in TensorFlow, access the layer that interrest you with the layers attribute, and merge them with the Functional API. One example could be the following :

```
import tensorflow as tf 

pretrainedmodel_files = ["A.h5", "B.h5"]

A,B = [tf.keras.models.load_model(filename) for filename in pretrainedmodel_files]

# Skipping the last dense layer and the dropout means accessing the layer at the index -3
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([A.layers[-3].output, B.layers[-3].output])
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="sigmoid")(concat)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[A.input, B.input], outputs=out)
```

---

I've created two simple model with the following code:

```
tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(5,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")
        ]
)
```

And then merged them together with my sample code.

A and B have the following architecture (visualization with netron):

[image]

And the merged network:

[image]

Comment: amazing! thank you for your precise answer (and for using netron, I will check this out!)